# Change scope variable from nested directive

Tags: angularjs, scope

In index.html I have

```
<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-cloak="" data-ng-controller="external">
    {{ modalLogin }} {{ modalRegister}}
    <topbar></topbar>
    <div class="modal__outer" data-ng-if="modalLogin || modalRegister">
        <modal-login data-ng-if="modalLogin"></modal-login>
        <modal-register data-ng-if="modalRegister"></modal-register>
    </div>
```

in external controller I'm declaring `$scope.modalLogin` and `$scope.modalRegister`. In topbar directive link function I'm changing this scope variables like this:

```
$scope.$parent.modalLogin = true;
```

and this works fine I can see that its value is changing and modal pop in. But then from modal directive inside it's link function I'm changing it back:

```
link: function ($scope) {
    $scope.hideModal = () => {
        $scope.$parent.modalLogin = false;
```

and something weird is happening because what I see in DOM modalLogin hides and got removed from DOM but .modal__outer div still remain:

and also values in view (interpolations) are not changed. Can someone explain me this behavior?

[image: img]

---

I gave up and used service as something like state (vuex/redux) in more modern frameworks.

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.

Comment: Well I'm not really new I was using this frameworks like 6 years ago and just stopped for modern frameworks and now I need to refactor old code and I totally forgot about what you noticed. Probably my mistake was that I needed to use $parent.$parent or something.

Comment: The use of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. While adding one or more `$parent` references may get the code to work, it is not a robust solution. Adding or removing `ng-if` directives will break the code. It is better to manupulate the property of an object on a scope rather the a property of scope directly.